# Простая геометрическая задачка

Tags: c++, c, математика

Эта задача из E-Olymp.https://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/924
Впринципе я все сделал, но программа работает не правильно.При любом значении,постоянно выводит 1,несмотря на то,что все необходимое уже написано(мне кажется).Не понимаю где ошибка.

```
#include"stdio.h"   
#include"stdlib.h"  
#include"math.h" 
 
int main(){   
    float Skol,R,r;   
    scanf("%f",&Skol);
    scanf("%f",&R);  
    r=pow(R*R- Skol/M_PI,1/2);  
    printf("%.2f\n",r);  
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Когда говорите "работает неправильно", то напишите, почему вы решили, что работает неправильно, т.е. какие данные вводите, что ожидаете и что получаете. Используйте кнопку править.

Comment: Да при любом значении,постоянно выводит 1,несмотря на то,что все необходимое уже написано.- @Roman Konoval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените `1/2` на `1.0/2`.

У вас целочисленное деление, и в результате получаете возведение в степень `0` независимо от входных данных. А это всегда 1.

То есть `1/2 == 0`, а `1.0/2 == 0.5`.